# List of .Net Numeric Type Initialization Identifiers

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm looking for a list numeric type initalization identifiers for both C# and VB.Net.

for example:

```
Dim x = 1D 'Decimal'
Dim y = 1.0 'initializes to float'
```

Here's the list:

The identifiers are case-insensitive

**VB.Net**

```
Int32   = 1, I
Double  = 1.0, R, 1.0e5
Decimal = D
Single  = F, !
Int16   = S
UInt64  = L, UL
```

**C#**

Comment: Me too... Too long I've had to rely on the docs (and memory) for this sorta list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### C#

[Section 1.8 of the C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(VS.71).aspx) includes these values.

> integer-type-suffix: one of U u L l UL
>   Ul uL ul LU Lu lU lu
>
> real-type-suffix: one of F f D d M m

[Section 2.4.4.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(VS.71).aspx) elaborates on this for Integer types:

> The type of an integer literal is
>   determined as follows:
>
> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which
>     its value can be represented: int,
>     uint, long, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by U or u, it has the first of these types in
>     which its value can be represented:
>     uint, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by L or l, it has the first of these types in
>     which its value can be represented:
>     long, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by UL, Ul, uL, ul, LU, Lu, lU, or lu, it is
>     of type ulong.

[Section 2.4.4.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691085(VS.71).aspx) elaborates on this for Real types:

> If no real type suffix is specified,
>   the type of the real literal is
>   double. Otherwise, the real type
>   suffix determines the type of the real
>   literal, as follows:
>
> - A real literal suffixed by F or f is of type float. For example, the
>     literals 1f, 1.5f, 1e10f, and 123.456F
>     are all of type float.
> - A real literal suffixed by D or d is of type double. For example, the
>     literals 1d, 1.5d, 1e10d, and 123.456D
>     are all of type double.
> - A real literal suffixed by M or m is of type decimal. For example, the
>     literals 1m, 1.5m, 1e10m, and 123.456M
>     are all of type decimal. This literal
>     is converted to a decimal value by
>     taking the exact value, and, if
>     necessary, rounding to the nearest
>     representable value using banker's
>     rounding (Section 4.1.7). Any scale
>     apparent in the literal is preserved
>     unless the value is rounded or the
>     value is zero (in which latter case
>     the sign and scale will be 0). Hence,
>     the literal 2.900m will be parsed to
>     form the decimal with sign 0,
>     coefficient 2900, and scale 3.

### VB

Similarly, the VB specification contains details for both [Integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711649(VS.71).aspx) and [Floating point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711650(VS.71).aspx) literals.

For integers:

> ShortCharacter ::= S 
>   IntegerCharacter ::= I 
>   LongCharacter ::= L

For floating points:

> SingleCharacter ::= F 
>   DoubleCharacter ::= R 
>   DecimalCharacter ::= D

Comment: It might be helpful say which value maps to which type.

Comment: Okay, I've added details from the language specifications. :)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't always use the identifiers, for exactly the reasons (memory) raised here. An interesting feature of the C# compiler is that it actually compiles the following to the same thing:

```
static void Foo()
{
    var x = 100F;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
static void Bar()
{
    var x = (float)100; // compiled as "ldc.r4 100" - **not** a cast
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

I find the second version far more readable. So I use that approach. The only time AFAIK that it does anything different is with decimal with trailing zeros - i.e.

```
static void Foo()
{
    var x = 100.00M;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
static void Bar()
{
    var x = (decimal)100.00; // compiled as 100M - extended .00 precision lost
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB you should have

Option Strict On

```
Dim x as Decimal = 1D 'Decimal'
Dim y as Double = 1.0 'initializes to double'
Dim z as Integer = 1 'integer
```