# What is the meaning of the special char in constant value

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of .Net Numeric Type Initialization Identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685962/list-of-net-numeric-type-initialization-identifiers)

What means the "D" in the following expression ?

```
Double total;

...

total = 30D;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It only means that you initialize your variable with a double value.

Here are the other characters used to specify the type of your constant value :

```
Decimal       = M
Float         = F
Long          = L
Unsigned Long = UL
Unsigned Int  = U
```

Answer (score 0):

'D' suffix is used to treat an integer as a double.